# Python PIP issue when installing Ray - The wheel package is not available

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install Ray - this can be done with a simple `pip install ray`

During the installation, packages get downloaded and installed correctly until it reaches **gpustat**

Python version: 3.8.7

OS: Linux (cflinuxfs3 to be more specific)

Here's the stacktrace

```
 Downloading https://masked-package-path/packages/packages/b4/69/gpustat-0.6.0.tar.gz (78 kB)
       ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
        command: /tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tdlwfmx8/gpustat/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-tdlwfmx8/gpustat/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-4yij8vu9
            cwd: /tmp/pip-install-tdlwfmx8/gpustat/
       Complete output (22 lines):
       WARNING: The wheel package is not available.
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
         File "/tmp/pip-install-tdlwfmx8/gpustat/setup.py", line 91, in <module>
           setup(
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 164, in setup
           _install_setup_requires(attrs)
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 159, in _install_setup_requires
           dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 699, in fetch_build_eggs
           resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 779, in resolve
           dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1064, in best_match
           return self.obtain(req, installer)
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1076, in obtain
           return installer(requirement)
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 758, in fetch_build_egg
           return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
         File "/tmp/contents295671398/deps/0/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 83, in fetch_build_egg
           raise DistutilsError('the `allow-hosts` option is not supported '
       distutils.errors.DistutilsError: the `allow-hosts` option is not supported when using pip to install requirements.
       ----------------------------------------
   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
   **ERROR** Could not install pip packages: could not run pip: exit status 1
```

Also, I tried installing `wheel` (because the WARNING is saying it's missing) but no luck.

Any known issues regarding **gpustat-0.6.0**?

Comment: `pip install gpustat==0.60` works for me with pip 21.0.1 and setuptools 51.1.0. What's your pip and setuptools version(`pip show setuptools pip`)?

Comment: *0.6.0, not 0.60

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error, but it was caused by gpustat's requirement for pytest-runner.

Running `pip install pytest-runner` fixed it for me. Just sharing in case anyone else has this problem.

Note: this was being done through a corporate proxy.

Comment: This worked for me!